# Cannot disable "white-space: nowrap;" on html div

Tags: html, css

On my website app, I have a logger window. In that window, I have table rows with divs inside.

I was able to crop long sentences for users. What I want is, when one hovers an item, it will show all sentences of that item.

It actually works for the last item. But why it does not work for the first item?

```css
.TGC_LibBootGUIDebug {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.TGC_LibBootGUIDebug:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="TGC_LibBootGUIDebug">- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vel commodo justo. Aenean vitae tellus vitae libero scelerisque tincidunt eu facilisis tellus. In tincidunt in mi in semper. Vivamus fermentum massa sagittis ullamcorper pulvinar. Ut id volutpat lectus. Nulla eget vulputate orci, id efficitur mauris. Donec lacinia consequat tortor vitae finibus. Phasellus a sem quis arcu iaculis finibus. Quisque tristique, purus ac sollicitudin efficitur, quam libero luctus massa, eget congue urna tellus ut dui.
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="TGC_LibBootGUIDebug">- Ut accumsan mattis eros ac hendrerit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean condimentum massa et vestibulum vestibulum. Aenean ac imperdiet arcu. Duis quis elit nibh. Nam tortor nunc, tristique eget dolor eu, placerat accumsan ligula. Mauris at odio cursus, scelerisque lectus nec, interdum erat. Sed facilisis ex vitae magna mattis dictum. Praesent molestie eros id diam sagittis pharetra. Donec sit amet tellus sem. Nullam iaculis nulla sit amet tellus bibendum, vel congue leo commodo. Cras accumsan imperdiet lorem, quis dictum arcu interdum a. In sollicitudin lacinia libero, sit amet accumsan enim mattis vitae.
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I figured out that removing table is solving the problem. But how to do with the table without changing code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `width: calc(100vw - 14px);` on `.TGC_LibBootGUIDebug{}` class. here the `px` I used 14 on codepen it's works for me.

You could customize it for yourself. check it from [here](https://codepen.io/raajkhan/pen/eYevVKp)

See example:-

```css
.TGC_LibBootGUIDebug {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: calc(100vw - 14px);
}
.TGC_LibBootGUIDebug:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="TGC_LibBootGUIDebug">- Ut accumsan mattis eros ac hendrerit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean condimentum massa et vestibulum vestibulum. Aenean ac imperdiet arcu. Duis quis elit nibh. Nam tortor nunc, tristique eget dolor eu, placerat accumsan ligula. Mauris at odio cursus, scelerisque lectus nec, interdum erat. Sed facilisis ex vitae magna mattis dictum. Praesent molestie eros id diam sagittis pharetra. Donec sit amet tellus sem. Nullam iaculis nulla sit amet tellus bibendum, vel congue leo commodo. Cras accumsan imperdiet lorem, quis dictum arcu interdum a. In sollicitudin lacinia libero, sit amet accumsan enim mattis vitae.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to set a width on your TGC_LibBootGUIDebug to make running the white-space correctly

```html
<style>
.TGC_LibBootGUIDebug {
    width:250px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.TGC_LibBootGUIDebug:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: normal;
}
</style><table><tbody>
<tr><td><div class="TGC_LibBootGUIDebug">- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vel commodo justo. Aenean vitae tellus vitae libero scelerisque tincidunt eu facilisis tellus. In tincidunt in mi in semper. Vivamus fermentum massa sagittis ullamcorper pulvinar. Ut id volutpat lectus. Nulla eget vulputate orci, id efficitur mauris. Donec lacinia consequat tortor vitae finibus. Phasellus a sem quis arcu iaculis finibus. Quisque tristique, purus ac sollicitudin efficitur, quam libero luctus massa, eget congue urna tellus ut dui.</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="TGC_LibBootGUIDebug">- Ut accumsan mattis eros ac hendrerit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean condimentum massa et vestibulum vestibulum. Aenean ac imperdiet arcu. Duis quis elit nibh. Nam tortor nunc, tristique eget dolor eu, placerat accumsan ligula. Mauris at odio cursus, scelerisque lectus nec, interdum erat. Sed facilisis ex vitae magna mattis dictum. Praesent molestie eros id diam sagittis pharetra. Donec sit amet tellus sem. Nullam iaculis nulla sit amet tellus bibendum, vel congue leo commodo. Cras accumsan imperdiet lorem, quis dictum arcu interdum a. In sollicitudin lacinia libero, sit amet accumsan enim mattis vitae.</div></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: What if you don't know the width that the cell should be?

Comment: for the sample i put a width in px to have a visual sample but if you don't want to "force" the width you can put a width in % it will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix the layout of your table, otherwise it will grow with its content. You can see the documentation for [`table-layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout).

In the example below, I'm using the fixed layout with a full width to demonstrate how it works.

```css
.TGC_LibBootGUIDebug {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.TGC_LibBootGUIDebug:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="TGC_LibBootGUIDebug">- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vel commodo justo. Aenean vitae tellus vitae libero scelerisque tincidunt eu facilisis tellus. In tincidunt in mi in semper. Vivamus fermentum massa sagittis ullamcorper pulvinar. Ut id volutpat lectus. Nulla eget vulputate orci, id efficitur mauris. Donec lacinia consequat tortor vitae finibus. Phasellus a sem quis arcu iaculis finibus. Quisque tristique, purus ac sollicitudin efficitur, quam libero luctus massa, eget congue urna tellus ut dui.
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="TGC_LibBootGUIDebug">- Ut accumsan mattis eros ac hendrerit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean condimentum massa et vestibulum vestibulum. Aenean ac imperdiet arcu. Duis quis elit nibh. Nam tortor nunc, tristique eget dolor eu, placerat accumsan ligula. Mauris at odio cursus, scelerisque lectus nec, interdum erat. Sed facilisis ex vitae magna mattis dictum. Praesent molestie eros id diam sagittis pharetra. Donec sit amet tellus sem. Nullam iaculis nulla sit amet tellus bibendum, vel congue leo commodo. Cras accumsan imperdiet lorem, quis dictum arcu interdum a. In sollicitudin lacinia libero, sit amet accumsan enim mattis vitae.
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The div does not have a width set, and white-space: nowrap is set, which causes the cell to be automatically stretched by the content. Just set a width for the div.

```
.TGC_LibBootGUIDebug {
    width: 400px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```